# How to rollback when input is less than 0 in SQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am building a database to keep track of stock, but I want to avoid selling more than the stock.

I am using Postgresql and I want to know if it is possible to use IF condition to check whether the UPDATE will result in negative number, if it is negative, then ROLLBACK?

I have seen documentation of IF, but not sure if it can be used to combine with ROLLBACK. Or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would just use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col check (col >= 0);
```

This will prevent any `update` or `insert` that would generate a `NULL` value in the column.

Comment: That will not prevent `NULL` values, for that you have to add a `NOT NULL` constraint

Comment: Then can it be combined with ROLLBACK? If it can, what is the syntax of it

Comment: @JetCat . . . There should be no need.  If you have a complex transaction and don't catch the check violation, then the transaction will be rolled back anyway.

Comment: this only affects to current row and does not check inventory over the table

Comment: @AliasgharAhmadpour - a check constraint applies to all rows in the table.

Comment: Yes,  you re right, i mean when we need to calculate all transaction to achieve the inventory and validate new row by that, this can't be done with check constraint.

Comment: @AliasgharAhmadpour . . . Of course it can be.  The check constraint needs to be on the `inventory` column, wherever that might be.

Comment: i don't know how it can be done, could you please explain how we can get sum of existing row and adding row to check if the inventory is not getting negative

Comment: for example we have some record with value {5, 3, -3, 1},the sum of the value is 6, if we wanna add (-7), how we can check it with check constraint.

Comment: @AliasgharAhmadpour . . . The question specifically says "the UPDATE will result in negative number".  To me, that clearly implies that some column is being updated which will result in a negative number.  Although your scenario might occur in some situations, it does not seem relevant to this question.  You are free, of course, to interpret the question differently, but it seems quite clear to me.

Comment: notice "I am building a database to keep track of stock, but I want to avoid selling more than the stock" in question

Comment: more than the stock means that check inventory and if exists then sell. good luck